# Filling the Android layout with elements

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

To clarify this - what I want to do is:

a) to open a http request to obtain some XML

b) parse that XML

c) given the (fixed) number of elements, put them with a bucle in the layout.

What I am missing is the last part. An example is 'twicca' or just the official Twitter application, that fills the layout with tweets. I want to do something like that. How should I proceed?

My first thought was creating a fixed number of TextView and change those TextView (TextView1, TextView2, ...) with the content I wish. But that  doesn't sound very professional...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to do this in Android is with a [ListView (link to developer guide)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html), which automatically creates as many items as needed from the data source. Most examples show pulling from a local SQLite database, but after you've loaded your XML items into an array in memory you can use an [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) as the data source for the ListView.

Comment: I am ashamed of not having thought of this before. Thank you very much!